# Set-AzureRmApiManagementPolicy : ValidationError: Resource was modified since last retrieval

Tags: rest, api, powershell, authentication, azure-api-management

When I try to call the **Set-AzureRmApiManagementPolicy** PowerShell commandlet to update a policy in Azure API Management, I get the following error:

*Set-AzureRmApiManagementPolicy : ValidationError: Resource was modified since 
last retrieval.*

This error only occurs when a policy already exists.  If I delete the policy and re-run it, then it works fine.  So, there's some strange issue with updating the policy once it's already there.  I know that this SHOULD work since I'm able to get this running if I call into **Login-AzureRmAccount** ahead of time and login.  Then the updating of an existing policy works.  It seems to be related to the way I'm authenticating with the Api Management REST API.  I'm using a certificate method of authenticating which is why I don't need to call **Login-AzureRmAccount**.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you set $DebugPreference="Continue" on the cmdline and provide the output? Open an issue at https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/new

Comment: OK.  I just submitted it to github.

Comment: We are tracking the issue at https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3817

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue is a result of a bug in the older "2014-02-14" api-version.  The PowerShell commandlet (***Set-AzureRmApiManagementPolicy***) is basically compiling down into a simple REST call which uses the 2014-02-14 api-version.  I checked the version of the PowerShell module *AzureRm.ApiManagement* by calling ***Get-Module -ListAvailable***

Since the AzureManagement module is bundled with the Octopus platform I'm using, there's no way for me to directly update it.  Therefore, I've made the decision to simply scrap the idea of using a PowerShell commandlet altogether and simply call into the Azure Management REST API directly.  Problem solved.